# How to call an Azure functions from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, webhooks

Can anybody guide me on the steps needed to call an azure function from SharePoint Online, normally functions are called after an item has been added to a list (webhook scenario)?

Comment: See Chris O'Brien's brief blog-post series: Calling an Azure Function from a SharePoint Framework web [part 1](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/04/calling-azure-function-from-sharepoint.html) & [part 2](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/05/call-azure-function-from-spfx-2.html).

Comment: @moe thanks exactly what i needed for a start. second step is how to use that in webhook list context.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft documentation is good.  Check out the SharePoint list webhook documentation here: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/webhooks/lists/overview-sharepoint-list-webhooks

Comment: the documentation is not for a beginner,they give codes sample but at that time i didnt know what to do with them. the chris obrien is good enough

Answer (score 1):

When you have a generic webhook created in azure functions you must only make an http POST call (With json formated data) to this from your sharepoint.